# Error installing nvidia-graphics on CentOS -- requires libGL.so()(64bit)

Tags: drivers, centos, yum

I am trying to install nvidia-graphics from atrpms, and it cannot install because of a dependency. It need libGL.so. I tried

```
yum install libGL.so.1
```

But I still can't get it to work.

The error is:

```
Error: Package nvidia-graphics325.15-libs-325.15-189-el6.x86_64
    Requires: libGL.so()(64bit)
```

EDIT: I used the following command to try to install (after successfully adding the atrpms repo):

```
yum install nvidia-graphics
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not show what command is that you are using to try to install the nvidia-graphics, but if it is an RPM that you are trying to install using the `rpm` command, try using `yum` instead because yum will try to resolve all of the dependencies. For example, if the RPM is named nvidia-graphics.rpm, then try

```
yum install nvidia-graphics.rpm
```

If it is not an RPM, then you can still use `yum resolvedep` to discover which package contains the libGL.so.1. For example,

```
# yum resolvedep "libGL.so.1()(64bit)"
```

returns

```
0:mesa-libGL-9.0-0.8.el6_4.3.x86_64
```

So, on my RHEL6 system, I would need to install the mesa-libGL-9.0-0.8.el6_4.3.x86_64 package via a command like `yum install mesa-libGL-9.0-0.8.el6_4.3.x86_64`. CentOS works the same way.

Comment: I added my installation line.

Comment: I tried the commands and got the same package you did. I tried to yum install that mesa package and it said it was already installed.

Comment: Is it possible that the system has 32-bit packages and 64-bit packages installed, too? Is the package yum says is already installed an x86_64 or an i386 or i686 package?

Comment: It is very possible and very likely.